# How does one typically do subgraph isomorphism?

Tags: memgraphdb

MAGE doesn’t seem to contain this algorithm. So I was wondering. Do I just build up a query that will match the subgraph(s) that I I am interested in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MAGE does contain such an algorithm inside the [`nxalg` module](https://memgraph.com/docs/mage/query-modules/python/nxalg#is_isomorphicnodes1-edges1-nodes2-edges2).

Simple example is:

```
MATCH (n:Label1)-[e]-(), (r:Label2)-[f]-()
WITH
COLLECT(n) AS nodes1
COLLECT(e) AS edges1
COLLECT(r) AS nodes2
COLLECT(f) AS edges2
CALL nxalg.is_isomorphic(nodes1, edges1, nodes2, edges2) YIELD *
RETURN is_isomorphic;
```